# Not able to install phpMyAdmin for PHP7 on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, php-7

I am not able to install phpMyAdmin for php7 on ec2 instance. I got an error when I am trying to install phpMyAdmin.

```
[root@ip-172-31-12-143 old]# yum -y install phpmyadmin
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1011 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check

---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.20-1.el6 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php(language) < 7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php(language) >= 5.2.17 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-zlib for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-zip for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-xmlwriter for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-spl for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-simplexml for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-session for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-pcre for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-mysqli for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-mcrypt for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-libxml for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-json for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-iconv for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-hash for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-gd for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-filter for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-date for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-curl for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-ctype for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-bz2 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.20-1.el6.noarch

--> Running transaction check

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.12-1.el6 will be installed


---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.13-1.el6 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(fedora/autoloader) for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.noarch

--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.noarch

---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.13-1.el6 will be installed

---> Package php56-common.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php56-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: php56-process(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: php56-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64

---> Package php56-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php56-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php56-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php56-mcrypt-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: php56-mcrypt-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64

---> Package php56-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php56-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-mysqlnd-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64

---> Package php56-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.1.2.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.4.2-20.4.8.3.31.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php-fedora-autoloader.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 will be installed

---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: libtidy-0.99.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-tidy-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

---> Package php56-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php56-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.6-1.19.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php56-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

---> Package php56-process.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed

--> Running transaction check

---> Package libtidy.x86_64 0:0.99.0-19.20070615.1.4.amzn1 will be installed

--> Processing Conflict: php70-common-7.0.21-1.23.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98

--> Processing Conflict: php56-process-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-process < 5.5.22-1.98

--> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Actual error is

```
Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

If you want to access your phpMyAdmin outside of local environment then edit file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` to allow access.

Comment: yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Error getting repository data for remi, repository not found

Comment: Download Repository as per your ec2 linux distribution and try this same command.